# Middleman Kramdown Converter for <a> html tags

Tags: ruby, middleman, kramdown

I'm trying to convert every kramdown link within a middlemanapp.

So far I've tried to prepend the `Kramdown::Converter::Html` module
and override the `convert_a` method.

```
module Kramdown
  module Converter
    module UrlConverter
      def convert_a(el, indent)
        "<a href=\"foo\">bar</a>"
      end
    end
  end
end

Kramdown::Converter::Html.prepend Kramdown::Converter::UrlConverter
```

But for some reason, `convert_a` is never executed. Methods like `convert_p` or `convert_codeblock` are executed and I can change their behavior.

Kramdown 1.10.0
Middleman 4.3.5

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Middleman overrides `convert_a` (and `convert_img`) in [`middleman-core/lib/middleman-core/renderers/kramdown.rb`](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/blob/61915cdaab387cfedd92bf25f35e2eb69ecd8f87/middleman-core/lib/middleman-core/renderers/kramdown.rb#L37) by deriving from `Kramdown::Converter::Html` and without calling `super`.

Therefore by prepending to `Kramdown::Converter::Html`, your method is replaced by middleman's version.

You might be more successful by monkeypatching `Middleman::Renderes::MiddlemanKramdownHTML` instead, but you'll need to be careful not to violate middleman's expectations of the `convert_a` method.